# How to construct a sequence with a pattern in R

Tags: r, sequence

I would like to construct a sequence with length 50 of the following type:
 Xn+1=4*Xn*(1-Xn). For your information, this is the Logistic Map for r=4. In the case of the Logistic Map with parameter  r = 4  and an initial state in (0,1), the attractor is also the interval (0,1) and the probability measure corresponds to the beta distribution with parameters  a = 0.5  and  b = 0.5. (The Logistic Map is a polynomial mapping (equivalently, recurrence relation) of degree 2, often cited as an archetypal example of how complex, chaotic behaviour can arise from very simple non-linear dynamical equations). How can I do this in R?

Comment: Your question is vague to me. Can you more explain?

Comment: For example, if X0=0.2, then X1=4*0.2*0.8, and so going on for X2, X3...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ready to use solution on the net. I cite the general solution of [mage's blog](http://www.magesblog.com/2012/03/logistic-map-feigenbaum-diagram.html) where you can find more detailed description.

```
logistic.map <- function(r, x, N, M){
  ## r: bifurcation parameter
  ## x: initial value
  ## N: number of iteration
  ## M: number of iteration points to be returned
  z <- 1:N
  z[1] <- x
  for(i in c(1:(N-1))){
    z[i+1] <- r *z[i]  * (1 - z[i])
  }
  ## Return the last M iterations 
  z[c((N-M):N)]
}
```

For OP example:

```
logistic.map(4,0.2,50,49)
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an `R` question, is it? More basic programming. Anyway, you probably need an accumulator and a value to process.

```
values <- 0.2              ## this accumulates as a vector, starting with 0.2
xn     <- values           ## xn gets the first value
for (it in 2:50) {         ## start the loop from the second iteration
  xn <- 4L*xn*(1L-xn)      ## perform the sequence function
  values <- c(values, xn)  ## add the new value to the vector
}
values
# [1] 0.2000000000 0.6400000000 0.9216000000 0.2890137600 0.8219392261 0.5854205387 0.9708133262 0.1133392473 0.4019738493 0.9615634951 0    .1478365599 0.5039236459
# [13] 0.9999384200 0.0002463048 0.0009849765 0.0039360251 0.0156821314 0.0617448085 0.2317295484 0.7121238592 0.8200138734 0.5903644834 0    .9673370405 0.1263843622
# [25] 0.4416454208 0.9863789723 0.0537419811 0.2034151221 0.6481496409 0.9122067356 0.3203424285 0.8708926280 0.4497546341 0.9899016128 0    .0399856390 0.1535471506
# [37] 0.5198816927 0.9984188732 0.0063145074 0.0250985376 0.0978744041 0.3531800204 0.9137755744 0.3151590962 0.8633353611 0.4719496615 0    .9968527140 0.0125495222
# [49] 0.0495681269 0.1884445109
```

Comment: The downvoting is an interesting approach. Would the downvoter care to comment?